# pvcreate No device found for /dev/vdb

Tags: rhel, lvm

I am having trouble using `pvcreate` command after a fresh install of Red Hat 9.3.  The goal here is to increase the size of `/dev/mapper/rhel-root`
so that I'm not running out of space.

`lsblk`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sr0            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
vda           252:0    0   35G  0 disk
├─vda1        252:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─vda2        252:2    0   19G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0   17G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]

[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vda: 35 GiB, 37580963840 bytes, 73400320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1649b049

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/vda1  *       2048  2099199  2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/vda2       2099200 41943039 39843840  19G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-root: 17 GiB, 18249416704 bytes, 35643392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/rhel-swap: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I need to increase the size of `/dev/mapper/rhel-root`.  I am using this as a
guidline to do this:

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/resize-lvm-simple

When I use `pvcreate` I always receive the following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/vdb
  No device found for /dev/vdb.
```

I have found a number of posts that talk about filtering and multipath but none of
these are configured currently..

Answer (score 2):

You're already running Logical Volume Management (LVM). You have shown that your VM knows only about its system disk, `/dev/vda`, and your command `pvcreate /dev/vdb` is trying to create a new Physical Volume (PV) on a device that does not exist ("*No device found for /dev/vdb*").

There is nowhere else you should be using this command, and there is no available space in your existing Volume Group (VG) on `/dev/vda2` to increase the size of your `root` LV.

If you have a second disk but the system hasn't noticed, the easiest fix is to shutdown and restart the VM. Then create a partition table spanning the entire disk and use `pvcreate /dev/vdb1` (it's safer than skipping the partition table and applying the PV to the raw space).

If it really is a fresh install and you want more than 17GB on your root partition, change the VM disk(s) to an appropriate size and start over.

Comment: Chris, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I'm going to post what I did to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get everything working correctly.  After creating a new disk
on the VM, these instructions worked perfectly...

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/resize-lvm-simple

1. Using cockpit, I added a new virtio disk to my VM.  In cockpit,
   click the disk tab on you vm and click add.  After a reboot, I
   could see that I have /dev/vdb now.  This is the piece I was missing
   from the start of this.

   ```
   [root@localhost ~]# ls -al /dev/vd*
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,  0 Feb  9  2024 /dev/vda
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,  1 Feb  9  2024 /dev/vda1
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,  2 Feb  9  2024 /dev/vda2
   brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252, 16 Feb  9  2024 /dev/vdb

   [root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/vdb
     Physical volume "/dev/vdb" successfully created.

   [root@localhost ~]# vgs
     VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
     rhel   1   2   0 wz--n- <19.00g    0

   [root@localhost ~]# vgextend rhel /dev/vdb
     Volume group "rhel" successfully extended

   [root@localhost ~]# vgs
     VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
     rhel   2   2   0 wz--n- 33.99g <15.00g

   [root@localhost ~]# vgdisplay
     --- Volume group ---
     VG Name               rhel
     System ID
     Format                lvm2
     Metadata Areas        2
     Metadata Sequence No  4
     VG Access             read/write
     VG Status             resizable
     MAX LV                0
     Cur LV                2
     Open LV               2
     Max PV                0
     Cur PV                2
     Act PV                2
     VG Size               33.99 GiB
     PE Size               4.00 MiB
     Total PE              8702
     Alloc PE / Size       4863 / <19.00 GiB
     Free  PE / Size       3839 / <15.00 GiB
     VG UUID               9XuyQe-49pL-Dm3c-1bWL-FU8c-omyJ-B9Vupu

   [root@localhost ~]# lvs
     LV   VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync 
   Convert
     root rhel -wi-ao---- <17.00g                                                  
     swap rhel -wi-ao----   2.00g                                                  

   [root@localhost ~]# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/rhel-root
     Size of logical volume rhel/root changed from <17.00 GiB (4351 extents) to 31.99 GiB (8190 extents).
     Logical volume rhel/root successfully resized.

   [root@localhost ~]# xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/rhel-root
   meta-data=/dev/mapper/rhel-root  isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=1113856 blks
            =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
            =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
            =                       reflink=1    bigtime=1 inobtcount=1 nrext64=0
   data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=4455424, imaxpct=25
            =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
   naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
   log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=16384, version=2
            =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
   realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
   data blocks changed from 4455424 to 8386560

   [root@localhost ~]# df -h
   Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
   devtmpfs               4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
   tmpfs                  2.8G     0  2.8G   0% /dev/shm
   tmpfs                  1.2G  8.7M  1.1G   1% /run
   /dev/mapper/rhel-root   32G   13G   20G  38% /
   /dev/vda1              960M  260M  701M  28% /boot
   tmpfs                  566M  4.0K  566M   1% /run/user/0
   ```

/dev/mapper/rhel-root is now only 38% full vs. 78% full before.

```
   [root@localhost ~]# lvs
     LV   VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
     root rhel -wi-ao---- 31.99g                                                   
     swap rhel -wi-ao----  2.00g
```

Comment: Really would have been better to create a partition table for the disk and put your PV in there

Comment: Also, now you've grown the XFS filesystem to use all the available space you've nothing left to handle unexpected growth elsewhere. (You can't shrink XFS.) Generally, when you're using LVM, do not use all the space at once but rather grow filesystems only as you need them

Comment: After spending over a day trying to increase the size of `/dev/mapper/rhel-root` and getting nowhere. I was just happy to get something working. If I need more space, I can add another disk.  I know there are better ways to do this but I do not want to spend another day on disks to figure it out.